# List most common members in Pandas group?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe with columns like this:

```
        id                           lead_sponsor lead_sponsor_class
  02837692    Janssen Research & Development, LLC           Industry
  02837679             Aarhus University Hospital              Other
  02837666  Universidad Autonoma de Ciudad Juarez              Other
  02837653         Universidad Autonoma de Madrid              Other
  02837640         Beirut Eye Specialist Hospital              Other
```

I want to find the most common lead sponsors. I can list the size of each group using:

```
df.groupby(['lead_sponsor', 'lead_sponsor_class']).size()
```

which gives me this:

```
lead_sponsor                              lead_sponsor_class
307 Hospital of PLA                       Other                  1
3E Therapeutics Corporation               Industry               1
3M                                        Industry               4
4SC AG                                    Industry               8
5 Santé                                   Other                  1
```

But how do I find the top 10 most common groups? If I do:

```
df.groupby(['lead_sponsor', 'lead_sponsor_class']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)
```

Then I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Comment: For me your solution works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['lead_sponsor', 'lead_sponsor_class']).size().nlargest(10))
```

In [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) is **Notes**:

> Faster than .sort_values(ascending=False).head(n) for small n relative to the size of the Series object.

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 2837692, 1: 2837679, 2: 2837666, 3: 2837653, 4: 2837640}, 
                   'lead_sponsor': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 's', 4: 's'}, 
                   'lead_sponsor_class': {0: 'Industry', 1: 'Other', 2: 'Other', 3: 'Other', 4: 'Other'}})

print (df)
        id lead_sponsor lead_sponsor_class
0  2837692            a           Industry
1  2837679            a              Other
2  2837666            a              Other
3  2837653            s              Other
4  2837640            s              Other

print (df.groupby(['lead_sponsor', 'lead_sponsor_class']).size())
lead_sponsor  lead_sponsor_class
a             Industry              1
              Other                 2
s             Other                 2
dtype: int64

print (df.groupby(['lead_sponsor', 'lead_sponsor_class']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).head(2))
lead_sponsor  lead_sponsor_class
s             Other                 2
a             Other                 2
dtype: int64

print (df.groupby(['lead_sponsor', 'lead_sponsor_class']).size().nlargest(2))
lead_sponsor  lead_sponsor_class
a             Other                 2
s             Other                 2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Just so I understand this - is the result of calling `.size()` a Series? I think I was confused because it looks like a dataframe, not a series (the way it prints the two columns to the left).

Comment: Yes, it is `Series`. You can test it by `print (type(df.groupby(['lead_sponsor', 'lead_sponsor_class']).size()))`
`<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`